# Table of Contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a document on my wiki page with multiple nested headings and I want them to be displayed as a Table of Contents (TOC) at the start of every page.

```
h1 Component description
    h2 About
    h2 Usage
       h3 Install
       h3 Configuration
       h3 Startup
```

Every page has different headings and thus will have a different TOC.

I have used the existing *Table of Contents web part* but it only lists all documents in my project and displays them as a TOC.

Is there a way to achieve it to behave like in Office.

Here is an example what I want to achieve but in [confluence](https://wiki.umms.med.umich.edu/display/demo/TOC+Examples)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via simple jQuery. All you need to do is to add the following script in your page layout or a Content Editor Web Part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".ms-rtestate-field h1,.ms-rtestate-field h2,.ms-rtestate-field h3,.ms-rtestate-field h4").each(function(){
                    if($(this).is("h2"))
                    {
                        if($(this).text()!=" ")
                        {
                            $("#wiki-index").append("<a style='margin-left:20px;' href='#"+$(this).text()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</a>")
                        }
                    }
                    if($(this).is("h3"))
                    {
                        $("#wiki-index").append("<a style='margin-left:40px;' href='#"+$(this).text()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</a>")
                    }
                    if($(this).is("h4"))
                    {
                        $("#wiki-index").append("<a style='margin-left:60px;' href='#"+$(this).text()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</a>")
                    }
                    if($(this).is("h1"))
                    {
                        $("#wiki-index").append("<a href='#"+$(this).text()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</a>");
                    }
                    $(this).prepend("<a name='"+$(this).text()+"'></a>");
                })

            });     

        </script>
```

Next, you would need to define an area to display your TOC, for this you would need to add a div

```
<div id="wiki-index">
                    <div class="toc">Table of Contents</div>
                </div>
```

After adding this script and div, when you insert headings in your wiki content `h1, h2, h3, h4`, this script would auto-generate a TOC upon saving your wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery for this "dynamic" task.
Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dinoskon/rr0rz2qb/1/